# How to modify a snapshot (commit) in a linear history without conflict-related errors?

Tags: git, rebase

During an interactive rebase one may get an error message like this:

```
% git rebase --continue
error: could not apply be3679b... shrink the kids

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply be3679bd31a31bd3869e17a66dc0b1b908282d94... shrink the kids
```

The verb "apply" (in `could not apply be3679b...`) clearly implies that `git` is treating commits as *patches*.  This flatly contradicts the frequently made assertion that `git` records ["snapshots, not differences"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#Snapshots,-Not-Differences) (since a patch is just a difference between two states).

For example, suppose that I have the following history on `master`:

```
                       HEAD
...---A-----B-----C-----D
                      master
```

...and I run `git rebase -i A`.  Suppose that I choose to edit `B`, nothing else.  I find that even if the changes I make to `B` do not involve deleting or adding files, I can still get errors of the type illustrated above ("could not apply ...").

To illustrate why these errors make no sense to me, here's a more laborious, but (crucially) *conflict-free*, way to produce the result I was trying to achieve with the interactive rebase above:

```
% git branch grmbl A
% git checkout grmbl
% git checkout B -- .
% # modify files in working directory to my heart's content
% git commit -a -m foo
% git checkout C -- .
% git commit -m bar
% git checkout D -- .
% git commit -m baz
```

(To make this equivalent to the original `git rebase -i`, let's assume that the commit messages I've used were the original commit messages for `B`, `C`, and `D`.)

At this point `git diff grmbl master` would show no differences.  This just as desired, since all I wanted to do was to change one *snapshot* along a sequence of *snapshots*, leaving all the other *snapshots* unchanged.

The key point is that the sequence above does what I want *without* `git` reporting any conflict-resolution errors.  Instead of "applying" a commit (as if it were a *patch*) to the current WD, I simply checkout the contents of that commit (with `git checkout <commit> -- .`).  The fact that this produces no conflicts makes the error reported by `git` during the seemingly equivalent interactive rebase operation all the more difficult to make sense of.

Is there a less laborious, but still conflict-free, way to achieve the effect achieved by the sequence above?

Comment: There is no contradiction: `git rebase` generates patches/diffs from commits, that is all.

Comment: @Jubobs: OK, I've changed the title of the question to make the point of it clearer.

Comment: I see you have accepted my answer. Does it completely answer your question, though? Do you need any clarification?

Comment: Sorry, I just accepted it.  It's a beautifully crafted post.  How did you do it so quickly?  It would take me a few hours to crank out the graphics alone.  I didn't accept it sooner because it didn't quite get at the heart of what prompted the question in the first place.  But it's so well done I couldn't not accept it.  FWIW, what I was hopeing for was some (reasonably knowledgeable/authoritative) clarification on 1) the head-on contradiction between what `rebase -i` actually *does* and the "`git` doesn't do differences--only snapshots" mantra; and 2) the fact that `git` (apparently) ...

Comment: ...does not even provide a command to do a pure "snapshot-only" rebase, and leaves it to users to do it in a laborious, error-prone way (which I illustrated).  (The "reasonably knowledgeable/authoritative" bit means to hint at some insider/historical-type knowledge on `git`'s philosophy or design that may explain what seems to me a very puzzling situtation; as opposed, that is, to the kind of educated guesswork that I can already do myself.)  As SE questions go, this one is admittedly quite arcane and probably answerable by relatively few people.

Comment: I wrote a tool called [gitdags](https://github.com/Jubobs/gitdags) for drawing those graphs; I often use it in my answers. You shouldn't feel obliged to accept the answer if it doesn't actually completely answer your question, even though you find the graphs pretty :) About your two points: 1) Git does manipulate commits, but derives/applies diffs when needed (in particular during a rebase). 2) I can't think of a way in which a "pure snapshot-only rebase" would make sense.

Comment: I think your second question stems from a misunderstanding of what `git rebase`, at its core, does. Have you read http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up.html? That might clear things up. Rebase started to completely make sense to me after I read that section of *Think like (a) Git*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The verb "apply" (in `could not apply be3679b...`) clearly implies that git is treating commits as *patches*. This flatly contradicts the frequently made assertion that git records ["snapshots, not differences"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#Snapshots,-Not-Differences) (since a patch is just a difference between two states).

I agree that the phrase

```
could not apply <commit>
```

is misleading. What you apply is really a *patch* that corresponds to the difference between `<commit>` and its parent (or, more generally, *one* of its parents). Therefore, the following message would be more accurate, and would perhaps make more sense:

```
could not apply patch from <commit-A> to <commit-B>
```

However, it's merely abuse of language, which, as you get used to it, becomes harmless. In English, you can say things like

> Bob drank the whole bottle of wine on his own!

and everybody would undertand that you're reporting about *Bob*'s wine consumption, not claiming that he ingested the container (bottle) itself.

You haven't been lied to; Git *does* indeed record snapshots/revisions/commits/states. Differences/patches are only generated from commits when needed; for instance, when using `git diff`, or `git cherry-pick`.

---

> [...] these errors make no sense to me [...]
>   The fact that this produces no conflicts makes the error reported by git during the seemingly equivalent interactive rebase operation all the more difficult to make sense of.

To explain why the interactive-rebase approach gives rise to conflicts, whereas your approach does not, let's consider a simple example: let's assume that the only tracked file in your repo is a file called `README`, and that the history looks as follows.

[image]

(The sheet of paper above/below a commit represents the the contents of the `README` file as recorded in the associated commit.)

### Your conflict-free approach

If you run

```sh
git branch grmbl A
git checkout grmbl
git checkout B -- .
# replace 'foo' by 'FOO'
printf "FOO\n" > README
git commit -a -m foo
git checkout C -- .
git commit -m bar
git checkout D -- .
git commit -m baz
```

you will end up with this:

[image]

Note that the version recorded in `B` and checked out in your working tree at the time of running

```sh
git checkout C -- .
```

simply gets overwritten by the version recorded in commit `C`. No patch gets applied anywhere, here; only a destructive checkout is involved; therefore, no conflict.

Also, as you correctly remark, in this case,

```sh
git diff grmbl master
```

would indeed return nothing, because those branches `master` and `grmbl` point to commits (`D` and `D'`, resp.) that record identical versions of the `README` file.

### Interactive-rebase approach

What happens when you run

```sh
git rebase -i A
```

is *very* different, in that it *does* involve applying patches. Everything is hunky-dory up until this point,

[image]

i.e. right after manually replacing "foo" by "FOO" and creating commit `B'`.

However, things go belly up right after that: interactive rebase attempts to cherry-pick commit `C` (in other words, apply the patch `B -> C`) on top of commit `B'`, but it finds no "anchor". More specifically, it attempts to add a `bar` line right after a `foo` line, but, of course, the latter is nowhere to be found, because, at this stage, the checked out version of the `README` file only contains a `FOO` line. Therefore, a conflict arises:

[image]

---

So...

> How to modify a snapshot (commit) in a linear history without conflict-related errors?

Well, even though interactive-rebase appraoch may give rise to conflicts, it's preferable, because it's more robust and automated. Your approach may be conflict-free, but it is also tedious (all those manual checkouts!) and error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

As Jubobs said, git does store history in a snapshot format.  However, when you are recreating commits with the `git rebase` command, it uses diff/apply to recreate the commits.

If you really want to do what you are proposing it is fairly simple but requires that you write your own script to replace rebase.

So what happens currently (simplified) is rebase generates a list of ORIG_SHAs in its todo list, and then calls `git diff SHA^1` for each SHA, and attempts to apply that diff.  You don't want that behavior.  What you want is to simply call commit tree with ORIG_SHA^{tree}.  You could do this by manually creating the commit, or doing a `git read-tree` of the original tree and throwing out the existing index.

Comment: The (complicated) script that lets you rewrite one commit in the middle of a sequence of commits is `git filter-branch`.  It's complicated because it's like rebase-on-steroids (whereas rebase itself is like cherry-pick on steroids, so this is steroids-squared :-) ) plus it's meant to run *non*-interactively.